# 404 Not Found on invoking resteasy webservice

Tags: java, web-services, rest, resteasy

I am new to RestEasy webservice. I am trying to implement Helloworld example using RestEasy. I made all the necessary configuration (like web.xml entries, applying annotations etc) to expose the resource method. Every thing looks good, but once I invoke the web service from Restclient, I am getting 404 Not found response.

I have the following code for this example:

**TestApplication.java**

```
package com.cole.wc.test.webservice;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
public class TestApplication extends Application{
  private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
  /**
  * @param args
   */   
  public TestApplication() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    System.out.println("RestEasy $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
    singletons.add(new TestImpl());
  }

  @Override
  public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
    return singletons;
  }
}
```

**TestImpl.java**

```
package com.cole.wc.test.webservice;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response; 

@Path("/webservice")
public class TestImpl{
  @GET
  @Path("/{param}/add")
  @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public Response printPathMessage(@PathParam("param") String param) {
    String result = "Simple webservice test success :  " + param;
    System.out.println("1 result --- "+result);
    return Response.status(200).entity("RestEasy Response").build();   
  }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0"  
metadata-complete="true">  

<servlet>
    <description>RESTEasy Servlet</description>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>com.cole.wc.test.webservice.TestApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/resteasy/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Below are the jar file(s) I included in my project.
"javax.ws.rs.jar"
"resteasy-client-3.0.13.Final.jar"

Below is the url I am trying to invoke from RestClient.
**http://localhost/MyApp/servlet/rest/webservice/{12}/add**

I see the output "RestEasy $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$" in console, from this  we can make out that control is reaching till TestApplication constructor.

Please let me know if I have missed any jars to include, or the URI is not correct.  Would you kindly point me in the right direction to successfully invoke this service.

Thank you for your time

Comment: how about this url ? http://localhost/MyApp/servlet/rest/webservice/12/add

Comment: Hi, I tried this URL also. No luck.